# Share library with dependencies

Tags: c#, dll, dependencies, libraries, dependency-management

I am currently working on a project with another company and my team is required to provide libraries for certain purposes. The source codes are not to be shared, so we should just build and send over the binaries.

While testing I came up with a problem. While building our library we used nuget packages and some of those will be in the target project, which will create a conflict if we just zip the bin folder and send it all.

Is there a way to just send over my main dll and reference the others as dependencies, so that when it is added to the target project as a reference they will be fetched as in nuget?

Many thanks

Comment: What about [creating a nuget package](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingANuGetPackageIn7EasyStepsPlusUsingNuGetToIntegrateASPNETMVC3IntoExistingWebFormsApplications.aspx) yourself? Is that an option? [How-To](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but no. We just need to send the binaries to be added as references

Comment: Hi, so no one has ever needed to share a dll with a third party?